# Lat/Long coordinates from measured depth

Tags: arcgis-pro, coordinates, latitude-longitude, borehole

I have a set of perforation data along a well bore that just includes measured depth (in feet).  I also have the directional survey for the same well that include survey points (measured depth in feet) with lat/long data along the well bore.

What I am trying to do is to figure out what the coordinates are for the perf data.  Is there a way to calculate lat/long for points with just measured depth?

The only way I have been able to do this is look at the directional survey and manually create points of where I estimate the perf points to be according to the directional survey points.  I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.

Comment: Are you saying that you have the latitude and longitude of a well location, you also have depths, distances, and directions of those perforation data from the well location, and you want to calculate the end point X,Y, and Z values of the perforations?  Maybe a drawing and some explanation of your terms might help.

Comment: What I have is point data for directional survey of a well that includes measured depth and lat/long data.  I also have another file of perforation data for the same well that only has depth in feet.  What I need to do is figure out the lat/long for the perforation data

Comment: Did you try simple linear interpolation of the perf measured depth value in the directional survey?